# Uniqueness of the CRT solution in $\mathbb Z_m$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

Suppose $x_1,x_2$ are solutions to:

\begin{align} x & \equiv c_1 \pmod{m_1} \\ & \,\,\,\vdots \\ x & \equiv c_k \pmod{m_k}\end{align}

Let's denote $M = \prod^k_{i=1} m_i$ and $y = x_1 - x_2$.

Hence, $$y\equiv 0 \pmod{m_i}\quad \forall i\in [k]$$

In other words, $$m_i \mid y \quad \forall i \in [k]$$

Since the $m_i$'s are co-prime then $$M\mid y \implies y\equiv 0 \pmod M$$

$$\implies x_1 \equiv x_2 \pmod{M}$$

I understand the proof, but, what if $M>y$? Then obviously $M\nmid y$

Or is it impossible? Why?

Comment: If $m_i's$ are co-prime and $m_i|y$ for any $i$ then $M\leq y$ by Arithmetic Fundamental Theorem.

Comment: I see, thank you @Gödel!